# want to do cumulative sum for multiple customer data

Tags: sql, postgresql, cumulative-sum

I same across a link in postgresql where I am able to generate series for cumulative sum. but it worked for single record. I have multiple customers data stored in one table I want to do sum for all customers. Below is code:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT date_trunc('month', pe.pdate) mon, sum(pei.pamt) as mon_sum 
FROM pur_entry_item pei, pur_entry pe, customer cus WHERE cus.id =  pei.cust_id 
AND pe.id = pei.pid AND cus.id=101 GROUP BY date_trunc('month', pe.pdate)
order by date_trunc('month', pe.pdate)
) 

SELECT to_char(mon, 'Mon YYYY') AS mon_text, 
COALESCE(sum(c.mon_sum) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY mon),0) AS running_sum 
FROM generate_series('2017-01-01'::date, now(),interval '1 month') mon 
LEFT JOIN cte c USING (mon);
```

by using above query it is possible for 1 customer to do cumulative sum from 01-01-2017 to current date if in between month data exists or not. now I have to do this for multiple customers. Any idea what should i do with this query.

```
TABLE 1 := pur_entry    TABLE 3 := customer
  id     pdate           id cus_name
  1    01-04-2017         1  nikita
  2    04-06-2017         2  disha
  3    10-06-2017         3  sonal
  4    10-09-2017
  5    01-06-2017         
  6    04-08-2017         
  7    10-10-2017        
  8    10-02-2017

TABLE 2 := pur_entry_item
 id cust_id pamt  pid
 1     1    1000   1
 2     1    200    2 
 3     1    500    2
 4     1    500    3
 5     1    100    4
 2     2    600    5 
 3     2    300    6
 4     2    200    7
 5     2    800    8

I want below result:
cut_id   date     amt
 1      04,2017  1200
 1      05,2017  1000
 1      06,2017  2200
 1      07,2017  2200
 1      08,2017  2200
 1      09,2017  2300
 1      10,2017  2300
 1      11,2017  2300
 1      12,2017  2300
 1      01,2018  2300
 1      02,2018  2300
 1      03,2018  2300
 2      04,2017  0
 2      05,2017  0
 2      06,2017  600
 2      07,2017  600
 2      08,2017  900
 2      09,2017  900
 2      10,2017  1200
 2      11,2017  1200
 2      12,2017  1200
 2      01,2018  1200
 2      02,2018  2000
 2      03,2018  2000
```

customer wise cumulatvie sum of purchase amount monthly. above code will work if only 1 customer for multiple customers generateseries will only generate series once.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect cumulative sum code to look like this:

```
SELECT cus.id, date_trunc('month', pe.pdate) as mon, SUM(pei.pamt) as mon_sum,
       SUM(SUM(pei.pamt)) OVER (PARTITION BY cus.id ORDER BY MIN(pe.pdate)) as cumulative_mon_sum
FROM customer cus JOIN
     pur_entry_item pei
     ON cus.id =  pei.cust_id  JOIN
     pur_entry pe 
     ON pe.id = pei.pid 
WHERE cus.id = 101
GROUP BY cus.id, date_trunc('month', pe.pdate)
ORDER BY cus.id, date_trunc('month', pe.pdate);
```

You can just remove the `WHERE` clause and do this for all customers.

Comment: Thanks but it is not giving me cumulative sum it will sum amount month wise. more ever it will not fill the months say suppose customer has purchased goods in march 2017 and after that in jan, feb 2018 then it should display 11 months of 2017 and 2 months of feb.

Comment: @charmi . . . I don't really understand your comment.  `cumulative_mon_sum` really should be a cumulative sum.  That is what this logic does.

Comment: hi gordan thank you for your reply. yes it is doing cumulative sum but if is only providing cumulative sum of month for which data is present. suppose for above example for cutomer 1 for month 5,7,8 data is not present so your provided query will no bring that month cumulative sum. I want missing month also.